# Promisified request does not return the proper result on resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise

I am trying to utilize `request` with Bluebird's `Promises`:

```
const request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));
Promise.promisifyAll(request);
```

Unfortunately, the result I am getting does not reflect what I was expected based on examples:

```
request('http://google.com').then(function(content) {
  // content !== String
  // Object.keys(content) => ['0', '1']
};
```

- content is not a string
- I have to access the content via `content['0']` respectively `content['1']` and here my actually expected response, the HTML string is.

This seems fishy to me, like I misused the Promise API here. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong. Have you checked the Latest API documentation. I guess they made a small change here maybe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.spread(function(response, content){})` instead of `.then(function(content){})`.

Comment: Can you explain what `spread` does? What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use native node's Promises?

```
function req() {
  return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
    request('http://google.com',function (error, response, body){
      if (error)
        reject(error);
      resolve(body) //if json, JSON.parse(body) instead of body
    });
  });
}
req().then(data => doSomethingWithData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use spread() instead of then().
Here is a link of bluebird, which explains the usage of spread().

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/2.x/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise

All the callback function of request is comprised of three params (err, response, content). In promisifed request, err is handled by catch().

But how to pass the other two parameters to the next chained callback function? It is not able to be achieved by then().

So promisifed request will return an array of two promises, one will return **repsonse** and the other **content**. And they can be caught by the spread() method, which is able to catch a fixed-size array of promises.